# draw lines between 2 points with AS3 code

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, line

I'd like to join multiple points with a line by clicking on them with AS3 code. Each time you click on a button it creates a line with a number.

I've created an animation in order to explain what I'd like to do. 
Here : **[Video link](https://sendvid.com/j1pjbhwj)**

[image]

What's your advice on the matter ?

I don't know the best method to do that. `graphics.lineStyle` ?

And which method can I use to count the number (first line created = 1, second line = 2 ..etc)

Comment: There are a lot of components involved to do this and covering all of them would be too long for this website (creating the graphics, adding them to the stage, registering event listeners for the clicks, finding the positions of where to draw the line from and to, drawing the lines, creating and adding text fields to the stage for the numbers). Is there a specific part of that process that you are having trouble with?

Comment: Well what have you tried so far? Surely you know integers, booleans, arrays, the AND `&&` operator, If/else?  So many valid ways to approach this. Not lineStyle but use `graphics.lineTo(a, b);` where `a` and `b` are the positions of two circles

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create `shape` first and draw it inside. Use `graphics.moveTo(x, y)` for setting the first point, and `graphics.lineTo(x, y)` for setting the second point. But use `graphics.lineStyle(thickness, color)` before it. Look for example [here](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/Graphics.html#lineTo()).

Comment: Instead of linking to the manual (which Asker should have read first anyway), I would suggest something more visual like **[this tutorial](http://www.republicofcode.com/tutorials/flash/as3drawvectors/)** to back up your answer. Otherwise +1 for useful.

Comment: You could improve your answer by telling them how to delete the lines as well, since it looks from their video like they need that.

Comment: For erasing any drawings use a `clear` method. For example like this:

`var shape:Shape = new Shape(); shape.graphics.lineStyle(1, 0xFF0000); shape.graphics.moveTo(0, 0); shape.graphics.lineTo(600, 600);`. There's drawing one red line. After that, when you need erase this, you can use `shape.graphics.clear()`.